# PHP modules, php-x vs php7.2-x

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, 18.04, php, extension

Upgrading Ubuntu from 16.04 to 18.04, I was facing a choice for some PHP modules.
Should I install, for instance

- `php-fpm`, or `php7.2-fpm`
- `php-gd`, or `php7.2-gd`
- etc...

since both names are available in the new OS (previous one was 7.0 on 16.04).

Some php modules are two-headed like the ones above, some exist only as `php-x`, some exist only as `php7.2-x`...

It seems the two headed ones give both the same version anyway (tried to install/uninstall a couple).

During an dist-upgrade, only the `php-x` ones are updated (since of course the new php having a higher version, the existing `php7...-` modules are marked in their names with a version that doesn't match the upgraded php...), thus requiring a check of all modules etc... post upgrade.

The whole seems quite confusing (would be better if all modules names were consistent...).

The questions:

- should I prefer the `php-` over the `php7.2-` modules? And why?
- subsidiary question: is there a reason to that double naming?

Comment: Install `php-x` and `php7.2-x` as the latter is the default php for bionic and the former is for all versions

Answer (score 1):

Install `php-x` and `php7.2-x` as the **latter** is the default php for bionic and the **former** is for all versions.

Based on OP updates, if they are two versions of a module say `php-x` and `php7.2-x` then install the latter where the required version isn't specific.

Comment: Ok but why not installing *only* `php-x` if both are available, so that it is automatically upgraded along with Ubuntu in 2 years -- what is the need of `php7.2-x` if `php-x` suffices(?)...?

Comment: That is left for the developers but from my experience using php this is what I have often done. I see tha `php-x` is usually for most versions and `phpx.x-x` are more specific